# WordPress 2.7: Creating Links on Posts Fail And Are Replaced by Javascript BS

Tags: wordpress, javascript

Trying to get a blog in order. I am currently running WordPress 2.7. I would like to upgrade to 3.0.1 but am having a problem. For some reason, if I add links in the post using the link button, the link is created but points to a JavaScript link. Case in point:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);/*1275378937689*/"><br />http://picasaweb.google.com/114701905311889616056/ServerCabinet</a>
```

Not sure why this is happening. Should I just upgrade to the latest version or is there something else wrong?

Anyone bumped into this problem? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some reason this is not just a matter of a permissions setting in your wordpress admin that allows or disallows adding links to posts, here are some tracks to try:

1. Rule out this being your browser. Disable all plugins/extentions (or run in something like a privacy mode that disables them all for you.
2. Rule out wordpress plugins on your site by disabling them all.
3. Audit your code and make sure it's all original WordPress source and not hijacked in some way.

Comment: I will look into that right now. Thx for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You're installation of WordPress has almost definitely been compromised by spammers. Version 2.7 of WordPress has known vulnerabilities and your site was probably easy to hack in to. Those links are probably part of some kind of blackhat SEO plot to exploit Google.

You need to completely replace all files in your file tree with ones that you know are uncompromised. Reinstall wordpress and all plugins and themes, upgrading to 3.0.1 to ensure that the new site is secure.

http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked